# CMD Closes when run as Windows Command Script, but not when manually pasted

Tags: node.js, windows, notepad++, notepad

When I save AFB_Auto & 2 as a Windows Command Script and run it, AFB_Auto closes but AFB_Auto2 remains open, when I type it manually or paste them Commandos 1 doesn't close, why is this?

**AFB_Auto**

```
cd desktop
cd agario-feeder-bot-master
npm install
npm install socket.io-client
start AFB_Auto2.cmd
cd server
node server.js
```

**AFB_Auto2**

```
cd desktop 
cd agario-feeder-bot-master 
node feeder.js
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Commandos 1 & 2`? Do you mean the two scripts `AFB_Auto` and `AFB_Auto2`?

Comment: omg im sorry! yes i do, i forgot to change AFB_Auto to commandos 1 in the above text when i wanted to be more specific :P